# Arrange controls in panel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to arrange the controls in a Panel control. For example, I have four labels and four textboxs, I want to put them in a panel like a table without using the VS designer, only use the code. Does anyone do it before?

Best Regards,

Comment: How exactly do you want them to look? How do you set 4 labels and 4 textboxs "like a table"?

Comment: yes,each row has a label and a textbox, only use the code.

Answer (score 2):

C#, and use styles to control layout.

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
Label lbl1 = new Label();
lbl1.Text = "1";
pnl.Controls.Add(lbl1);
TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
pnl.Controls.Add(tb1);
Page.Controls.Add(pnl);



label
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it form it, I want to only use the C# language。

Comment: This is in C#. The controls are being created in the code and added to the page.

Comment: @James Thomas, I updated my answer after him comment. He should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could essential do the same thing Visual Studio does on the back end.  Create a new control and set the properties, such as: size, name, text, and location.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can simply create a custom control that contains a label and a text box. Let's call this control LabeledTextBox. And then on your code simply add 4 instances of LabeledTextBox one after the other. This should provide the look and feel you want.